# Get count of only required column data from a laravel controller output

Tags: laravel-4

```
$selected_subcats2 =  EstablishmnetSubcategories::Join('establishments','establishments.id','=','establishment_subcategories.establishment_id')->where('establishment_subcategories.establishment_id',$establishment_id)->get(array('establishment_subcategories.status as status'));

Result:[{"status":0},{"status":1},{"status":1},{"status":0},{"status":0}]
```

This is my controller condition and output, in the above output i want to get the count of status whose value is only zero . i dont want count of all , how its possible to get only status zero count, please help ...thank you

Comment: add `where status=0` condition

Comment: Yes, got it thank you Bhargav

Comment: if you dont mind so i can post this comment as answer

Comment: yes, sure.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Add `where('status',0)` in your Query

it will work